# Find all transactions in which a program was redeployed

Tags: rpc, program, ledger

How to get all transactions, when a specific Solana program was redeployed given I only have a program address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [`getSignaturesForAddress`](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#getsignaturesforaddress) to retrieve all the transactions that a particular account has been involved with.

Most programs have to be buffered due to their size so you would expect to see the following transactions

1. `SystemProgram::CreateAccount` & `BPFUpgradeableLoader::InitializeBuffer`
2. A bunch of `BPFUpgradeableLoader::WriteBuffer`
3. Finishing up with a `BPFUpgradeableLoader::Upgrade`

Doing `getSignaturesForAddress` on the payer, for a specific period, may be one way to get these transactions. Alternatively, you can use the buffer account for the search as it is involved in all of the above transactions.

Comment: Thank you! How then can I find this buffer account?

Comment: What info do you _have_ to begin with? If you provide some more details in the question, I can be more specific.

Comment: I have program address and that's pretty much all. That's why the question is so broad

Comment: The program ID is involved in the last transaction `BPFUpgradeableLoader::Upgrade` so you can start there, get the buffer account from that transaction and then work backward. Here is an example: https://explorer.solana.com/tx/43CSYFNyJihgrL739LoR2UWYrEWg3wxjvx4nF6XK98wmPVqSbX3ipstaujViShSDkrqy3yNpLVH1UzXb5Ds5bYfz. Note "Program Account" and "Buffer Account"